# Com visualizar PDF gerados com Laravel-dompdf no viewer.js?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-5

Tenho uma aplicação `Laravel` que gera relatórios em `PDF` de acordo com parâmetros recebidos de um formulário via POST e gostaria de visualizar os arquivos gerados com o `viewer.js` ***sem precisar salvar os arquivos em diretório*** e a função utilizada para gerar os relatório em `PDF` é:

```
public function generateReport(Request $request){
    $dataset = Report::where('idfilial', '=', $request->idfilial)
               ->whereBetween('datamovimento', [$request->datainicial, $data->datafinal])
               ->get();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHtml(view('report.pdf', compact('dataset')));
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Comment: Com esse plugin não, ele só aceita o caminho de um arquivo em disco, como está explicado na sua [documentação de instrução](http://viewerjs.org/instructions/)

Comment: Já encontrei alguns exemplos usando um encode base64, algo parecido com isso: viewer.html?file=data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQxxxxx
Mas guante tentei fazer não deu certo

Comment: Cole aqui os links do exemplos!

Comment: por causa da quantidade de caracteres, adicionei o link de exemplo a um docs.google que você pode acessar por esse link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1t01HuDEC01QulzTXw_jRqmoEA3C7M1LfLlv7b45f7-4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Um base64 de Hello Word é uma coisa de uma documento grande não vai suportar

Comment: No entanto, se você abrir o link do exemplo que te envie e substituir o encode base64 pelo encode base64 de qualquer outro pdf ele funciona. Mas se eu fizer da mesma forma no meu projeto não funciona. Então acredito que seja apenas uma questão de configuração, mas não encontrei nada na documentação